# Play sound in a fragment

Tags: java, android, audio

I want to press an image button and it should play an mp3 file in raw.

Here is my code and error in it -

```
public class Fragment_food_apple extends Fragment{

    MediaPlayer MediaPlayer;
    ImageButton btn;
    public Fragment_food_apple() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.apple);
        //////problem is in up line and it is under this,
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mp.start();
            }
        });

    };
```

Comment: show stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Method `MediaPlayer.onCreate()` requires an object of class `Context` as its first parameter, you are passing Fragment (which doesn't subclass Context) to it.

Use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` instead.

Hope this helps you, comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I missed something, but here you go. If you get any error, just let me know.

```
MediaPlayer mp;
ImageButton btn;
public Fragment_food_apple() {
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Inflate
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false);

    //Find media player
    mp = MediaPlayer.create (getContext(), R.raw.apple);

    //Find your button
    btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON);       

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mp.start();
    }
});


};
```

Comment: Fragments didn't have `getContext()` until API 23 (I'm not sure about support in AppCompat, though), so you probably shouldn't use it unless you really want to target only API 23+ devices

Comment: thank you for your help     now problem is that inflater and container are both red(???) could you help me more???

Comment: Oh and in inflater instead of `fragment_timer` use your own fragment class. Forgot to change.